# Regexp for login

Tags: regex

I have a string must begin with a letter, consist of letters, numbers, periods and minus, but only end with letters or numbers; the minimum length of - one character, maximum - 20. Here I wrote test lines where last must be ignored:

```
abcAA123.-as
a
aa
aA
a1
a1a
a.a
a-s
ad.a1
ads.a
a-12
A-j
A.b
A.....-bg
v--.1.2.3.a.s..d.fg45.--..
```

My regex is `\w?(\w|\.|\-)+?\w+` and its match last string and don't match `a`. Where is my mistake? How I can write right regex?

Comment: What **language** are you using?

Comment: `string must begin with a letter`, `but only end with letters or numbers;` . i think you don't want to match the strings which has single digit.

Comment: @hwnd I am using C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use lookarounds.

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9]$)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d.-]{0,19}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uN4lT5/6)

- `(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9]$)` Asserts that the match must ends with a letter or digit.
- `[A-Za-z]` Must starts with a letter.
- `[A-Za-z\d.-]{0,19}` matches the chars according to the pattern present inside the char class. And the number of matched chars must be from 0 to 19.

Answer (score 1):

Your Regex matches only strings with at least 2 characters. The `?` in the part `(\w|\.|\-)+?` makes the quantifier lazy which means it matches as few as possible but the `+` quantifier matches at least one character. You should replace the `+` with a `*` if you want that part to match at least none.

Edit:
I've noticed that my answer was incomplete at best. The regex I came up with looks like this `^[a-zA-Z](?=[\w\.\-]*?\w$)|^[a-zA-Z]$`. This one matches either the first letter of every string that starts with a letter and ends with either a letter or a number `^[a-zA-Z](?=[\w\.\-]*?\w$)` or that only contains one letter `^[a-zA-Z]$`.

Comment: You're right. I've only read to the point where he can't match the single letter 'a'. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[\w.-]{0,19}[0-9a-zA-Z]$
```

Simply use this and you are good to go.Your currect regex does not work as it reuqires at least 2 cahracter.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/40

Answer (score 0):

The actual regexp is

```
[a-z]?(.|\-)+(\w+|\b)
```

It wouldn't match `a` because it has a word ending character immediatly after it. its matched by `\b`

http://rubular.com/r/eP8D6pmCnQ